# Read/Write large data fast way

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am taking backups of VHD in GB's currently using single thread. i want to reduce time for reading/writing in c++. Now i want to use multiple threads each thread will read a perticuler blocks and write at same location in output file no thread will write at same place.
I have done with first part of reading file using multiple threads using multiple `std::ifstream`, Now i want to reduce write time but i am not able to use multiple `std::ofstream` , Using single `ofstream & Mutex` i am not getting a good result as i expect....Plz help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the reason you're getting errors with the ofstream is because you're opening the file for exclusive access. If you want multiple writers to a single file, you'll have to specify file sharing options.

Using multiple reading and writing threads won't speed things up. Your bottleneck is the disk, and it can do only one thing at a time. Using multiple threads will actually slow you down because there will be unnecessary disk seeks.

Why you're writing a C++ program to do a VHD backup is a little bit of a mystery. You could use COPY or ROBOCOPY or download and use [Fastcopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en), which is the fastest file copy program I've used on Windows.

If you really want to write your own copy program, do it with two threads: one for reading, and another for writing. It works like this:

```
Read the first block
while not end of input
    Make an asynchronous call to start writing the block
    Read the next block
    wait for the asynchronous write to complete
end
```

Note that this won't improve your performance if the input and output files are both on the same physical disk. If the source and destination are on the same drive, then multiple threads won't help you at all.

Comment: Thanks, But i am reading a VHD of VM on VMWare Esxi server and writing ot linux system will COPY or ROBOCOPY or download will it work for this because i am reading data using VDDK api@Jim Mischel

Comment: @Dipak: I'm not familiar with any special tools for Linux, or with VMWare.